# $scope var not placing data inside index file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

Can anyone tell me why my code will not place 'controller is working' inside

{{jsVariable}} ?? I'm going out of my mind over this.

HTML code:

```
<!-- AngularJS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script> 

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controller.js"></script>
```

... ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller">

```
<h1>asd {{jsVariable}} asd</h1>
```

Controller code:

```
    app.controller('controller', ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';
    $scope.bob = function() { 
        console.log("bob: " + $scope.jsVariable);
        $scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';

    }

}]);
```

In the console I do get a secsessful 'bob: controller is working'

UPDATE:

I'll make it even simpler:
index file:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controller.js"></script>
```

**//body (for some reason stackoverflow will not allow me to place the body, div, and head tags, but then do exist in my code)**

..div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

```
<h1>asd {{jsVariable}} asd</h1>
```

..div>

app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

controller.js file:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

    $scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';



}]);
```

Comment: Show your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` or if you bind the controller from the routes..

Comment: Is you HTML all correct? You have your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` set?

Comment: See updated code for ng-app

Answer (score 0):

I think you might not have set your ng-app and/or ng-controller. I have a version of your code that displays here:

html

```
  <html data-ng-app="app"><!-- I set up ng-app here -->
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script> 

<script src="controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="controller"> <!--I set the ng-controller here -->
<h1>asd {{jsVariable}} asd</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

I don't think I changed the angularjs, but just in case:

```
 let app = angular.module('app', []);

 app.controller('controller', ['$scope',function($scope) {

$scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';
$scope.bob = function() { 
    console.log("bob: " + $scope.jsVariable);
    $scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';

}


}]);
```

Comment: I just updated the code with my app.js file. However I don't use `data-ng-app="fooBar"`. I use `ng-app="fooBar"`. Is this not the correct way?

Comment: HTML 5 validators like to see the 'data' part, so I always put it there. I don't know the reason. For any use I've had ng-app and data-ng-app have functioned identically.

Comment: I notice on your updated index file you don't have angular linked anymore. Is it still linked in your actual file? What I have above is working for me. I put the app part into a separate file and linked it like you have and it was still working.

Answer (score 0):

You just create the Function $scope.bob but you never call it.
Just add a new line with $scope.bob();

Something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
    Anything you want
</div>
<script>

    var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myAppModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';

        $scope.bob= function () {
            console.log("bob: " + $scope.jsVariable);
            $scope.jsVariable = 'controller is working';
        };

        $scope.bob();
    }]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added `$scope.bob();` but I am still getting nothing in my browser.

Comment: Did you try with my code? It is working, it shows in the console the message